# Parse Error Before 'End-Of-Line'

Tags: vb6

I'm developing memory management program, that the `Form1_Load` Sub is like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    HeapSize()
    HeapFree()
    HeapMax()
    StorageSize()
    StorageFree()
End Sub
```

But when I try to compile it, I'm getting this:

> Compiling...
>   frmMain.hbf (1) : error #2000 : parse error before 'end-of-line'
>   frmMain.hbf (2) : error #2000 : parse error before 'end-of-line'
>   frmMain.hbf (3) : error #2000 : parse error before 'end-of-line'
>   frmMain.hbf (4) : error #2000 : parse error before 'end-of-line'
>   frmMain.hbf (5) : error #2000 : parse error before 'end-of-line'
>   
>   MemManager - 5 error(s), 0 warning(s).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the five method calls inside `Form_Load` are all `Sub`s (as opposed to `Function`s), in which case you need to remove the parenthesis from after the method name:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    HeapSize
    HeapFree
    HeapMax
    StorageSize
    StorageFree
End Sub
```